# How do I copy the lines of file in between two patterns and store in an array in PHP

Tags: php

My current PHP code iss:

```
$searchFor="Sum";
$handle=@fopen("assets/lib/basic.lib"); //this if my file consisting of sum structure
if($handle){
while(!feof($handle)){
    $buffer=fgets($handle);
    if(strpos($buffer,$searchFor)!==FALSE)
      $matches[]=$buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This is `basic.lib` file:

```
Sum: start
Sum: op1 =
Sum: op2 +
Sum: op *
Sum: end

Sub: start
Sub: op1 =
Sub: op2 -
Sub: end
```

The above php code helps to retrieve all the lines having substring `sum`

**But i want to redesign the `basic.lib` file as:**

```
Sum:start
output 1: Hello
output 2: world
Sum:end

Sub:start
output 1: Hello
output 2: Again
Sub:end
```

So how can i the lines between **Sum:start** and **Sum:end** in the `$matches` array now .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: does `Sum:end` line always be the ending(last) line?

Comment: I copied the whole line of file using `fgets` and stored in `$matches`. made the structure of file as `sum:start` `sum: op1 =`, `sum: op2 +` before. But i thought that the structure mentioned in the question above will be more feasible @Epodax

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `sum: end` is always the ending line for `sum` block. The other block starts like `subtract:start`.

Comment: Like @Epodax said, show us what you have tried! Your comment is a first step but still a bit confusing. Please edit your question and provide some original code. Sure we can help then!

Comment: @matthias , okay i have tried to include the codes. Check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution with `file` function:

```
$arr = file("assets/lib/basic.lib");
$capture = false;
$needed_lines = [];

foreach ($arr as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, "Sum:start") !== false){
        $capture = true;
        continue;
    } elseif (strpos($line, "Sum:end") !== false) {
        $capture = false;
    }
    if ($capture){
        $needed_lines[] = $line;
    }
}

var_dump($needed_lines);
// the output:   

 array (size=2)
  0 => string 'output 1: Hello
' (length=17)
  1 => string 'output 2: world
' (length=17)
```

Comment: thanks , this worked the way I wanted. Just had to modify `Sum:start` with `$searchFor:start`

Answer (score 0):

You can split text file into array and check for particular string in each element:

```
$filename = "txtfile.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $contents);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, ':start') !== false || strpos($value, ':end') !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
$arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => output 1: Hello
    [1] => output 2: world
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please check the updated question above. I have tried to clarify the need